# Cannot push to github from vs code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-push

I tried to put my code into a GitHub repository and when I add a remote name it said:
***fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/abc.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+error%3A1407742E%3ASSL+routines%3ASSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO%3Atlsv1+alert+protocol+version

Answer (score 0):

You may have an outdated version of git installed, since GitHub disabled tlsv1 connections time ago.

Try updating git to its [latest version](https://git-scm.com/downloads).